# Why is MongoDB very slow on update requests when running using docker compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a single instance mongodb node using [docker-compose](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

I'm trying to update 40k documents.
I tried running this on 3 setups of aws instances - 2x4 (cpu/mem), 4x8 and 16x32.

It seems that even after adding more cpu, the task doesn't run faster.

Also in top it shows that cpu of mongodb is always 100% during this task.

Any way to improve this?

Comment: Mongo actually uses multi-core when during reading, when writing happens, it always uses single core. In order to increase write speed, you can look into sharding setup which can increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [iostat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) to determine what the cpu is spent on.

If it is spent on iowait, your system is i/o bound and adding more cpu won't help - you need faster disks.